# Packages as plugins in Python

Tags: python, plugins, packaging, extending

What is the best way to extend a python package via optional packages? The idea is that you could so:

```
pip install mypackage
```

and optionally:

```
pip install mypackage-option1
```

Then you application will do:

```
from mypackage import somefunction
```

but `somefunction` is aware of the existence of `mypackage-option1` if it is installed.

I have seen a few ways of doing this via plugin systems, but I have a few requirements that I need to fulfill:

- Python 2.6+ and 3.2+.
- Zero configuration.
- `mypackage` should not explicitly use `mypackage-option1`. (i.e. if in the future I have `mypackage-option2` it should work without changing `mypackage`)
- The application using `mypackage` should not need to import `mypackage-option1`
- No configuration files or list stored in the user directory or anywhere else.

Comment: Why not use `from mypackage-option1 import somefunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plugin packages' names will always start with `mypackage-` (and with your no-configuration requirement you probably need a convention like that), you can do:

```
import pkgutil
plugin_names = [
    name for (loader, name, ispkg) in pkgutil.iter_modules()
    if name.startswith('mypackage-')]
```

That will get you the package names as strings. Then you can use `__import__()` to dynamically import modules.